# Issue with rewire.js - Error: Cannot find module <path to rewired module>

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

So my directory structure looks like this:

[image]

and this is basically the cookie cutter use case for the [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) library right?

So my test module is very bare bones, just trying to rewire the module I want to test.

**fetchTerms.test.js**

```js
import test from 'ava';
import rewire from 'rewire';
let fetchTerms = rewire('../src/fetchTerms.js');
let dateIsValid = fetchTerms.__get__("dateIsValid");
test("dateIsValid catches invalid dates", t => {
    t.false(dateIsValid("999999"));
    t.is("", "a");
});
```

**fetchTerms.js**

```js
...
function dateIsValid(date) {
    let month = parseInt(date.slice(4));
    return 1 <= month && month <= 12;
}
...
export default <some other function>;
```

Unfortunately when I run with ava, I get this "cannot find module" error caused by the attempted rewire

```sh
> ava


  ✖ No tests found in target/test/fetchTerms.test.js

  ─

  Uncaught exception in target/test/fetchTerms.test.js

  Error: Cannot find module '../src/fetchTerms.js'

  › internalRewire (node_modules/rewire/lib/rewire.js:23:25)
  › rewire (node_modules/rewire/lib/index.js:11:12)
  › file://target/test/fetchTerms.test.js:3:18
  › ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:138:23)
  › Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:178:24)

  ─

  1 uncaught exception
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fetch_courses@1.0.0 test: `ava`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fetch_courses@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /mnt/c/Users/********/.npm/_logs/2020-07-22T03_11_15_418Z-debug.log
```

Unless you can find anything wrong with the rewire path `../src/fetchTerms.js` I don't know what could possibly make rewire not know how to find `fetchTerms.js`.

Any ideas?

Comment: The rewire readme says it's only compatible with Common JS modules. You're using ES6 [https://github.com/jhnns/rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire)

Comment: thats really annoying i like es6 @EvanMorrison thanks tho

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire